# Access to disposed closure warning using Azure Transient Fault Handling Retry Policy

Tags: c#, azure, resharper

We have a worker role which processes records and sends Azure service bus messages as needed based on the results of the query, this is basically a queue processing service.  As part of the best practices of using SQL Azure, we have wrapped all of our query statements with a retry policy (this detects transient errors and will retry based on the defined policy).  Note that we actually send the message from within the using statement so there is no 'leak' of the db variable.

Inside of our using statement, ReSharper is throwing up the 'Access to Disposed Closure' warning, most likely because we are passing our DataContext as a func parameter of the retry policy.

My question is, am I OK in my assumption that ReSharper is not detecting this pattern correctly or are there alternative methods in how we write these functions in order to prevent the warning above?

**The Code**

*The db variable in the retryPolicy.ExecuteAction is what is getting flagged*

```
using (var db = new MyEntities())
{
   var thingsToUpdate = retryPolicy.ExecuteAction(() => db.QueueTable.Where(x => x.UpdateType == "UpdateType" && x.DueNext < DateTime.UtcNow).Take(30).ToList());
   if (!thingsToUpdate.Any())
   {
      return;
   }
   while (thingsToUpdate.Any())
   {
      var message = new ServiceMessage{
                            Type = "UpdateType",
                            Requests = thingsToUpdate.Select(x => new ServiceMessageRequest
                                {
                                    LastRan = x.LastRan,
                                    ParentItemId = x.ThingId,
                                    OwnerId = x.Thing.ForiegnKeyid
                                }).ToList()
                        };
      SendMessage("UpdateType", message);
      foreach (var thing in thingsToUpdate )
      {
          thing.LastRan = DateTime.UtcNow;
          thing.DueNext = DateTime.UtcNow.AddMinutes(10);
      }
      retryPolicy.ExecuteAction(() => db.SaveChanges());
      thingsToUpdate = db.QueueTable.Where(x => x.UpdateType == "UpdateType" && x.DueNext < DateTime.UtcNow).Take(30).ToList());
     }
}
```

**Additional Information**

I also posted this to the ReSharper forums for a broader audience and this particular issue was addressed in a little more detail over there.  For posterity, you can find the [question here.](http://devnet.jetbrains.com/message/5482748)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I guess your ExecuteAction executes your lamdba immediately. Then you should annotate a lambda parameter from your ExecuteAction method with ReSharper's attribute [InstantHandle].

For example:

```
public void ExecuteAction([InstantHandle] Action action)
{
  ...
}
```

You can either import JetBrains.Annotations.dll to get this attribute or just copy all of attributes inside your project. See more info on JetBrains site [here](http://www.jetbrains.com/resharper/webhelp/Reference__Options__Code_Inspection__Code_Annotations.html) and [here](http://www.jetbrains.com/resharper/webhelp/Code_Analysis__Code_Annotations.html).

Comment: Thanks - indeed it does return immediately and there should not be any problems with disposed closures. I don't have control over the assembly to add the [InstantHandle] attribute.  I will suppress the messages with inline comments for the time being.

Comment: @Tommy If you don't have access over the assembly, then you can add external annotations. See here http://www.jetbrains.com/resharper/webhelp/Code_Analysis__External_Annotations.html